# Redis ACL, creation of a user who has different permission on different set of keys

Tags: redis, acl

I have been trying to create a user who has read permission for a certain set of keys(user.{userId}.*) and must have permission to execute any command on all other keys/a set of keys(com.mycompany.*).

Can you please help me in creating such a user in Redis using cli?

I tried doing this

1 - ACL SETUSER test3 on >test123 ~user.user123.* +@read

2 - ACL SETUSER test3 on >test123 ~com.mycompany.* +@all

but +@all overrides read and I can modify the keys starting with user.user123.* after the execution of 2nd command, which shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis ACL not support it now. The `ACL Rule` for `key access` and `command access` is splited. Thus not supported for different keys with different access command.

Comment: Small note: we're hoping to improve ACL in that respect in the next version. See https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/7291

Comment: Happy to see the improve of ACL, I will track it.